# javascript reduce function not running logic

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am writing a function that is going to do a series of logic tests on an input. I am using the lodash library.   So for this particular example if there is an ID = 123ABCZ, it must contain one of the items.

```
_.contains(list, obj.id) && _.contains(list, item)
```

I only have one object currently ( in item_arr ) in there but sometimes I have many which is why I have a temp obj that is flattened.  if I pass in ['123ABCZ', 'apple'] it should return true but it is not.  It should also return true if the ID is not present at all too. I can't figure out where the logic went wrong!

```
function include_test(list){

    var item_arr = [{id: '123ABCZ', item: ['apple', 'pear', 'grape', 'lemon', 'lime']}];

    var functionizer = function(obj){
        var func_arr = _.map(obj.item, function(item){
            return function(){
                            if(_.contains(list, obj.id)
                    return _.contains(list, obj.id) && _.contains(list, item);
                            return true;
            };
        });
        return func_arr;
    };

    var temp = _.flatten(_.map(item_arr, function(item){
        return functionizer(item);
    }));

    var result = _.reduce(temp, function(acc, func){
        acc = acc || func();
        return acc;
    }, false);

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple issues here. What is functionizer actually returning? An array of functions that have lost scope of their arguments and their referenced variables. You need a closure... well several of them.

Here's an example with closures.

```
function include_test(list){

    var item_arr = [{id: '123ABCZ', item: ['apple', 'pear', 'grape', 'lemon', 'lime']}];

    function functionizer(obj){
        var _obj = obj;
        return function() {
            _.map(_obj.item, function(item){
                return (function(itemRef, listRef, objRef){
                           if(_.contains(listRef, objRef.id)
                               return _.contains(listRef, objRef.id) && _.contains(listRef, itemRef);
                               return true;
                       })(item, list, _obj);
            });
        }
    };

    var temp = _.flatten(_.map(item_arr, function(item){
        return functionizer(item);
    }));

    var result = _.reduce(temp, function(acc, func){
        acc = acc || func();
        return acc;
    }, false);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: functionizer returns an array of functions.  in my example it returns _.contains(list, obj.id) && _.contains(list, item); for each iteration of items.  I'm only getting 'undefined; when I try to run your example.

Comment: What is the result you're getting in your example, false or undefined or error?

Comment: I was getting false, but something is sort of working now... I think something is happening with if(_.contains(list, obj.id)).   When I ive it an obj.id that I KNOW is contained, it never enters the if statement...